# Opposite of tidyr::separate, concatenating multiple columns into one

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2, 3),
    `1` = c("W4", "W5", 49),
    `2` = c("L", "O1", "P6"),
    `3` = c(1, 2, 10),
    `4` = c("H7", NA, "K"),
    `5` = c("J8", NA, NA)
)
```

How can I concatenate/paste the columns together with `sep = ","`

(The opposite of tidyr::separate(), I guess?)

Desired output:

```
id  string
1   W4, L, 1, H7, J8
2   W5, O1, 2
3   49, P6, 10, K
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

I'm wary of using `paste` because in my real dataset I have 1000 columns.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `unite` function from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
unite(df, string, X1:X5, sep = ", ")
#  id            string
#1  1  W4, L, 1, H7, J8
#2  2 W5, O1, 2, NA, NA
#3  3 49, P6, 10, K, NA
```

Note that it also has a `remove` argument that is `TRUE` by default. If you set it to `FALSE`, the original columns are kept in the data.

For the column specification (which columns to unite) you can use the colon operator (`:`) as I did above or use the special functions described in `?dplyr::select`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I'm embarrassed that I didn't know about unite. TIL.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this in `base R` without any packages

```
data.frame(id = df[1], string= do.call(paste, c(df[-1], sep=",")))
#  id        string
#1  1  W4,L,1,H7,J8
#2  2 W5,O1,2,NA,NA
#3  3 49,P6,10,K,NA
```

Comment: I liked your solution, nice

Comment: @Learner Thank you for the comment

Answer (score 0):

another way could be to do as follows:

```
mdf <- df %>% transform(strings=paste(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5, sep = ","))
mydf <- mdf[,c(1,7)]
> mydf
#  id       strings
#1  1  W4,L,1,H7,J8
#2  2 W5,O1,2,NA,NA
#3  3 49,P6,10,K,NA
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another example using 'unite', which does the opposite of 'separate'...

Starting with the following data frame, df, which has 3 columns ('year', 'month', and 'day'):

```
df

  year  month day          

1 2009  01    01
```

If we wanted to concatenate the 'year', 'month', and 'day' columns into a single column called 'time', using a hyphen as a separator, we can use unite:

```
df %>% unite(time,c("year","month","day"),sep="-")


  time     

1 2009-01-01
```